# Django form validation failing - pytz and choices

Tags: python, django, django-forms, pytz, django-timezone

I am trying to let the user set which timezone they are in, however form validation `.is_valid()` is failing and cannot figure out why.

- The timezone value for a user is stored in a Profile model.
- Using `ChoiceField` and `pytz.common_timezones` to fill the form field

This would be appear to be quite simple to do, the only thing thats different to my usual way is that the data filling the combo/select box is the use of a `ChoiceField` and the data is coming from `pytz`.

I may switch to [django-timezone-field](https://github.com/mfogel/django-timezone-field) to solve this, but I would like to understand why it is failing. I have included all relevant (I think) code below. Any suggestions?

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    timezone = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
    )
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProfileEditForm(forms.Form):

    profile_timezone = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in pytz.common_timezones])
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def userprofile_edit(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        profile_edit_form = ProfileEditForm()

        if profile_edit_form.is_valid():
            cd = profile_edit_form.cleaned_data

            user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)

            user.profile.timezone = cd['timezone']
            user.profile.save()

            messages.success(request, "Profile updated successfully", fail_silently=True)
            return redirect('coremgr:userprofile', request.user.id)

        else:
            messages.error(request, "Error occured. Contact your administrator", fail_silently=True)
            print "error: form not valid"
    else:
        profile_edit_form = ProfileEditForm()

    context = {
        'profile_edit_form': profile_edit_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'apps/coremgr/userprofile_edit.html', context)
```

**template**

```
<form name="formprofile" method="POST" action="">
{% csrf_token %}

<p id="profile_timezone" class="form-inline">
{{ profile_edit_form.profile_timezone.errors }}
Timezone:
{{ profile_edit_form.profile_timezone }}
</p>

<button id="id_btn_profile_edit_save" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" tabindex=7>Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `request.POST` in form

```
if request.method == "POST":

     profile_edit_form = ProfileEditForm(request.POST)
```

Comment: Ahhh haha....so obvious, don't understand how I missed that! Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to pass in request.POST when initializing the form in your if block.